# Transplanted brain then finds flesh repulsive short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was a short story I read about 1990 in the UK - I can't remember if in a magazine or a SF anthology.

Some guy has had his brain (or maybe just his consciousness) transplanted into a humanoid body, I can't remember why.

He's getting counselling to get accustomed to it but he's having other issues, he now finds humanity disgusting and unhygienic. He keeps focusing on things like an attending nurse has a small pimple appearing on her cheek but it now horrifies him.
Another person he sees with a tiny dot of sleep at the corner of his eye (not sure about this, it could be a miniscule scrap of snot at his nostril).

These issues get worse and it's eventually resolved by him going fully robotic with a large insectoid body, he's now scuttling across the sterile lunar landscape so he doesn't freak out at repulsive people.

However he keeps glowering up at planet Earth because he sees it as a giant ball of corruption and pus.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's *[Masks](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41166)* by Damon Knight.

It ends

> The prospector was climbing a crater slope with its handling members retracted and its head tilted up...And he was there, and it was not far enough yet, for the Earth hung overhead like a rotten fruit, blue with mold, crawling, wrinkling, purulent and alive.

(He's not actually non-humanoid yet, just drawing a picture and thinking about it, right after he kills the dog for grossing him out with its "shiny nose, wet eyes" and "wet red tongue".)

Comment: Very funny, as it seems the OP has offered this exact short themselves in another answer :P https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/269323

Comment: @fez googling it vs remembering it I guess

Comment: @fez - That's hilarious.

Comment: Haha I remember answering that now! I really can't believe I forgot it - I was on a bus this morning and somebody was sat  beside me - he had a giant pimple on his cheek that looked ready to pop .....I was thinking "what's that story about somebody repulsed by flesh because he's now a robot?" My brain just couldn't come up with it!

Comment: @DannyMcG that describes my brain most days.